# Handing double clicks in GTK#

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, gtk, gtk#

I'm converting a `WinForms` app over to `GTK#` and I want to simulate the `OnMouseDoubleClick` method on a `GTK# DrawingArea` widget.

In `WinForms`, you have two methods you can override, one for a single click and one for a double click. If `WinForms` only detects a single click, it only calls the `OnMouseSingleClick` method, and if it detects a double click, it only calls the `OnMouseDoubleClick` method.

Now in GTK#, you only have a single method you can override for clicking, `OnButtonPressEvent`. If you single click, `OnButtonPressEvent` only gets invoked once, but if you double click, it gets invoked three times! This is because GTK sends a signal for each click, PLUS one for the double click.

There are similar questions on this site but none of the answers have been about the widget I'm using, or the answers weren't satisfactory. So my question again is, how do I simulate `WinForms` `OnMouseDoubleClick` method with `GTK#`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GTK doesn't offer the behavior implemented by WinForms, likely because it entails a delay before a genuine single click takes effect. (Without that delay WinForms would emit at least one spurious `OnMouseSingleClick` before `OnMouseDoubleClick`. This delay is very visible when you use single-click to rename a file in a file manager that also uses double-click to open the file.)

To implement it yourself, you need to do the following, in pseudo-code:

1. Add a boolean `wait` and an unsigned `handlerId` member to your class. Set `wait` to false.
2. When `OnButtonPress` receives a single-click and `wait` is false: Set `wait` to true and use `GLib.Timeout.Add` to schedule an `OnWaitForDoubleClickTimeout` method to run after the delay equal to the GTK double-click interval. You can obtain the double-click interval as the `gtk-double-click-time` property from [`Gtk.Settings`](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aGtk.Settings). Store the return value of `GLib.Timeout.Add` in `handlerId`.
3. When `OnButtonPress` receives a single-click and `wait` is true: Cancel the timeout by calling `GLib.Source.Remove(handlerId)`, reset `wait` to false, and otherwise ignore the event.
4. When `OnButtonPress` receives a double-click: Invoke `OnMouseDoubleClick()`. At this point, due to #3, `wait` should be false.
5. In `OnWaitForDoubleClickTimeout`, reset `wait` to false and invoke `OnMouseSingleClick`. Finally, return `false` so the same timeout doesn't fire again.

Comment: I've been on this problem for days but shortly after asking this question, I came up with an answer similar to yours. You coming up with a similar answer really validates my own solution. Thanks for the extra details though! This is what I came up with: http://pastebin.com/6P3uZJPV

Comment: @fdpierson Yes, your code uses the same general idea. One difference is that it also introduces a delay before double-click is responded to, which might be noticable to the user. The pseudocode in the answer introduces a delay only for single-clicks, where it's necessary to distinguish a true single click from the first click of a double click.

Comment: Also, it would be a good idea to read `gtk-double-click-time` from `Gtk.Settings` instead of hard-coding it to 250ms.

Comment: Taken note of. Also, you got to upgrade to GTK# 3 if you want to remove `TimeoutHandlers`, at least without returning `false` from them. You can't remove them any other way in the version of GTK# included with MonoDevelop. I had to upgrade just now.

Comment: @fdpierson That's quite surprising. As far as I can tell from the documentation, `GLib.Timeout.Add` returns a `uint` which you can pass to `GLib.Source.Remove()`. But even if the timeout handler can't be removed, it can be effectively disabled using an additional flag visible to the handler.

Comment: That really caught me off guard because `GLib.Idle` has a `Remove` function. Thanks again!

Comment: @fdpierson I've now updated the answer to include this information for posterity. :)